# How to send multiple requests with Axios?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, formik

I'm working on a react registration form which contain some fields (idStudent(primary key & auto increment), first name, last name, ....., faculty, prerequisites), I'm using Formik & yup for validation.

Later on, I have to link my app with a recommendation system (recommend a final year project to students) based on prerequisites and the obtained grades in some subjects.

At first, I used just one table to store the data coming from the form in frontend,
**student(firstname, lastname, ... ,prerequisites)**
A student can select prerequisites from a react select that contain prerequisites according to the faculty (example : if a student study computer science, the react select will show only computer science prerequisites like react, angular, machine-learning ....).
Taking into consideration a student can have multiple prerequisites, so the prerequisites column in students table will contain multiple id's of the selected prerequisites,
The prerequisites are stored in an other table in my database **( prerequisites(idFaculty, idPrerequisites, prerequisite) )**
I know that I can store multiple id's in one column using a JSON file but after some researches here on Stackoverflow in some previous posts, I found that it's difficult to deal with JSON especially if I want to update a column.
So I created another table to store the selected prerequisites by a student when registering
**(studentPrerequisites(idStd (foreign key reference to idStudent from students table), idPrerequisite(foreign key reference to idPrerequisites from Prerequisites table))**
The problem I'm facing is how to send two post's requests via axios, taking into
consideration that maybe I should use a loop to store multiple rows in case a student select multiple Prerequisites.
This is what I did :
My backend file

```js
app.post("/registerStudent", (req, res) => {
  const faculty = req.body.faculty;
  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO students (email, password, firstName, lastName, faculty, phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
    [email, password, firstName, lastName, filiere, phone],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        // store chosen prerequisites
        //result.insertId is the current idStudent of the student who registering
        const idStd = result.insertId;
        const idPrerequisite = req.body.idprerequis;
        db.query(
          "INSERT INTO studentPrerequisites (idStd, idPrerequisite) VALUES (?,?)",
          [idFiliere, idPrerequisite],
          (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              res.send("Values Inserted");
            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
  );
});
```

My frontend code

```js
const onSubmit = (values, actions) => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/registerStudent", {
      faculty: values.faculty,
      firstName: values.firstName,
      lastName: values.lastName,
      phone: values.phone,
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password,
    })
      .then(() => {
       //preId is an array  that contains the selected prerequisites(id's) from react select  
       //I try to use a for loop to store multiple of prerequisites dynamically in case a 
       //student select multiple prerequisites
        for (let i = 0; i < preId.length; i++) {
            idPrerequisites: preId[i],
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("success!");
      });
    actions.resetForm();
  };
```

Comment: Why do you need to send multiple posts? Btw string list of ids as a delimited list of values, is worse than using json...

Comment: Because in the Form i have a react select, the options of that select are prerequisites, each prerequisite have an id, if a student select 4 prerequisites, that means I should send 4 posts, to save them in 4 rows in studentPrerequisites table, every row have same id student and different id's prerequisites

Comment: I don't wanna store string ids, i want to store every ID individually

Comment: Why would you need 4 post requests for that? Send just one with an array of prerequisites.

Comment: `Taking into consideration a student can have multiple prerequisites, so the prerequisites column in students table will contain multiple id's of the selected prerequisites` this does sound like you want to store list of ids as delimited string

Comment: Suppose that a student when registering select 4 prerequisites (python,  machine-learning,  vue.js) whose ids respectively 1, 2, 3, MySQL doesn't support saving an array, that means i can't just send one request, for that I need to send multiple requests, a request to store informations like firstname, lastname, email... In students table, and other requests according to how much prerequisites a student select, the prerequisites should store them in another table (idStudent, idPrerequisites)

Comment: Yes, you can send just one request! You process the request on the server side and generate multiple sql insert statements.

Answer (score 1):

It might be best to let the backend handle multiple prereqs by passing in an array of prereqs to your request. I'd also use Knex and async/await to avoid a lot of .then chaining and to make use of transactions. Transactions will revert all queries if any errors occur within the transaction. Knex also makes querying databases super easy with built-in methods instead of writing raw SQL. You should also be using object destructuring instead of doing firstName = req.body.firstName, lastName = req.body.lastName, etc. You can learn more about knex and getting your db connected to it here: https://knexjs.org/guide/#node-js
Also, WHY ARE YOU NOT HASHING YOUR PASSWORDS? That is the most basic security you should be doing at a minimum!

[image]

Comment: It seems great to work with Knex and maybe easier, but unfortunately I have many queries in my server-side which seems difficult to me to handle with Knex, because I did not use Knex before, and I didn't have so much time left to complete the project (it's my final year project ),  that's why I think it's better for me to write my queries without using a SQL query builder. I tried the code you suggested but it didn't work to me, Most of the time I'm wrong about something even though I configure correctly and I tried a get request with Knex and it's worked for me.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can do it with just normal SQL queries ?